# Wrong CPU load average, Fedora 28 + Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, cpu-usage, fedora-28

For some reason, my "top" command is showing wrong cpu average. Like 100% cpu usage everytime, but, in fact, the cpu is 100% idle.

It's a Raspberry 3, running Fedora 28. CPU temperature is below 46C, so, the CPU is really idle. No hardware changed in last months.

Any idea why?

```
top - 21:47:52 up  1:02,  1 user,  load average: 4.00, 4.00, 4.00
Tasks: 139 total,   1 running,  84 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.5 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.0 id,  0.0 wa,  4.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :   996680 total,   210940 free,   294880 used,   490860 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   249852 total,   249852 free,        0 used.   680308 avail Mem
```

As you can see, CPU is idle for some time, but:

```
load average: 4.00, 4.00, 4.00
```

It's fixed in 4.00 all time, in a 4 CPU machine.

Using `iostat` shows correct cpu load average (~99% idle).

Comment: Who is voting down this question?

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to launchpadmcquak ([link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96312)):

> Found. There appears to be a bug in the vhciq driver in the 5.0.x kernel:
>
> https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2881
>
> Reverting back to a 4.x kernel appears to solve this problem.
>
> https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1231413

My kernel was updated some days ago, and the problem started after a reboot.

```
Removed:
  kernel.armv7hl 4.20.15-100.fc28          
  kernel-core.armv7hl 4.20.15-100.fc28 
  kernel-modules.armv7hl 4.20.15-100.fc28 

Installed:
  kernel.armv7hl 5.0.5-100.fc28                                                 
  kernel-core.armv7hl 5.0.5-100.fc28                                            
  kernel-modules.armv7hl 5.0.5-100.fc28
```

Comment: Always nice to see people answering own questions. Thanks.

Comment: @davidbaumann The question was [cross-posted](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/96250) and the answer is somebody else's.

Comment: Yes, I referenced the original user, because it's from Raspberry forum, not SuperUser, so, I cannot direct link the user.